# How can I select a radiobutton in a webradiogroup t

Tags: hp-uft

Im new in UFT. How can I select a radiobutton in a webradiogroup? I have to determine first if the status is available and select the first availablr in the radibutton. TAKE NOTE every date i have selected the available status beside radiobutton is changing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the value you select try this:

```
'Always select the first value

    Browser("index:=0").Page("index:=0").WebRadioGroup("name:=[RadioGroupName]").Select "1"
```

If you need to extract the values from the group and parse for a specific one you could pull all the values

```
values = Browser("index:=0").Page("index:=0").WebRadioGroup("name:=[RadioGroupName]").GetROProperty("innertext")
```

and then make an array and parse that:

```
arr = split(values, ";")
```

For more advanced techniques I'd recommend buying a copy of Tarun Lalwani's QTP Unplugged books:
QTP Descriptive Programming Unplugged: Master Object Identification Techniques
or
QuickTest Professional Unplugged (2nd Ed.)

Most of the code samples in these books still work in the MicroFocus' modern UFT 14.53 tool.